# Multivariate normal imputation model Jomo R package

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, multiple-imputation

I have three questions about multivariate normal imputation using R package `jomo`. I modified the example in `jomo` to illustrate the questions:

```r
library(jomo)
Y <- JSPmiss[, c("english", "ravens")]
X <- JSPmiss[, c("cons", "sex")]

set.seed(1569)
imp1 <- jomo(Y = Y, X = X, nburn = 1000, nbetween = 1000, 
             nimp = 5)
imp2 <- jomo(Y = Y, nburn = 1000, nbetween = 1000, nimp = 5)
imp3 <- jomo(Y = JSPmiss[, c("english", "ravens", "sex")], 
             nburn = 1000, nbetween = 1000, nimp = 5)
```

1. What are the differences between the three imputation models? Does it mean that imp2 and imp3 don't have a predictor in the imputation model?
2. Why the variables in X can't have any missing values? Can "ravens" be a predictor for "english" in the imputation model? It seems that multivariate normal imputation **only** uses **the fully-observed variables** to impute missing values, which is different from MICE, which can use **both** fully- and partially-observed variables to impute missing data.
3. Can partially observed auxiliary variables be also included in multivariate normal imputation model? How it can be specified/included?